# Are there any OpenGL implementations which can use a server to do the rendering?

Tags: windows-7, linux, unix, graphics-card

Assume I have 2 independent machines, one running Debian sid, and the other running Windows 7.

The one running Debian sid has a decent graphics card, the Windows 7 machine has no graphics card and a weak processor. The two are connected over a fast local network.

Are there any OpenGL implementations, where Windows 7 would use the Debian machine's graphics card to do OpenGL rendering "over the network"?

**Update:**
I have found Chromium **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28computer_graphics%29** which seems to be what I'm looking for. I will try setting it up and I'll report back.

**Update:**
I have set it up, and the OpenGL commands are sent to the Debian machine, but also is displayed on the Debian machine. Not every OpenGL program works, and it is buggy, but it is possible. I haven't set it up so that the render would show up at the Windows machine, but it should be possible according to the documentation.

At first I was unable to compile it on Windows 7 properly (Cygwin, MinGW, VC++), but here's a github project which adds CMake support, with which I was able to build it successfully in Visual Studio Express 2010 https://github.com/rpavlik/chromium .

Comment: What you want does not exist.  You basically want to do cloud graphical computing.

Comment: In addition to what @Ramhound mentioned, bandwidth and latency bottlenecks make this extremely impractical. The bandwidth of, for example, a PCI Express x16 slot is something around 4GB/s and it, ostensibly speaking, has zero latency. Even with a gigabit network interface and ~1ms latency, real-life performance of such a system would be seriously gimped.

Comment: @user1973386 - Amazon recently annouced a new graphical cloud computing service.  I will post information on the service withn 24 hours.

Comment: You guys are assuming things. OpenGL isn't just used to produce real-time animation, it's also used for ray tracing scenes of detail sufficient that the latency you speak of doesn't much matter. You send an OpenGL program to the server and minutes later it sends back a rendered raster image. Wouldn't matter it took a second to send it down the wire, obviously.